# Distinguishing sign of zero : -float64(0) from float64(0) in Go

Tags: go, ieee-754, zero

I want to serialize a floating point in such a way that sign info is not lost.  Specifically, I would like to distinguish IEEE-754 negative zero from regular zero.

The [language spec](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Arithmetic_operators) says

> The result of a floating-point division by zero is not specified beyond the IEEE-754 standard; whether a run-time panic occurs is implementation-specific.

which suggests that I cannot do

```
n == 0 && (float64(1) / n) < 0
```

and I tried `math.Copysign` and [`math.Signbit`](http://golang.org/pkg/math/#Signbit) which says

> ```
> func Signbit(x float64) bool
> ```
>
> `Signbit` returns `true` if x is negative or negative zero.

but

```
n == 0 && math.Signbit(n)
```

doesn't seem to work for

```
n := -float64(0)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I filed [issue 2196](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=2196) to track what I think is a confusing difference between

```
nz := -float64(0)
```

and

```
pz := float64(0)
nz := -pz
```

as suggested by peterSO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    pz := float64(0)
    nz := -pz
    fmt.Println(pz, math.Signbit(pz), nz, math.Signbit(nz))
    if n := nz; n == 0 && math.Signbit(n) {
        fmt.Println("n is negative zero:", n)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 false -0 true
n is negative zero: -0
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand.  The sign is lost in `-float64(0)` but not when you do the explicit extra operation.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get the go playground ( http://golang.org/doc/play/ ) to generate a -0 from literally typing it in source; I'd speculate the compiler converts it to 0.

However, I could generate a -0 like this:

```
fmt.Println(0);
fmt.Println(-0);
hmm := -1 / math.Inf(1);
fmt.Println(math.Signbit(hmm));
fmt.Println(hmm);
```

Prints:

```
0
0
true
-0
```

Comment: one could wonder if the unit tests for atan2 which test for -0 are actually working as the author intended them to?

Comment: Ah, so I was failing in my testing to properly generate a real -0 value.